# É possível receber notificação quando são feitas novas perguntas em uma tag?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso

É possível receber notificação quando são feitas novas perguntas em uma tag?  Seria bem cômodo.

Comment: Isso era ótimo. Ainda esta semana andei a pesquisar sobre isso e até no http://stackapps.com mas não encontrei nada que funciona-se.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O site não oferece isso diretamente, porém existe um feed Atom por tag que você pode acompanhar. Por exemplo, o feed de perguntas recentes de [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r):

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=r&sort=newest
```

O link para o feed fica na lista de perguntas recentes da tag, abaixo da paginação:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

A metade acima pretende responder à parte "suporte" da pergunta. Sobre a parte "novo-recurso", o que posso dizer é que apoio. A implementação depende do staff do site e das prioridades deles.